# 0x800A03EC When Reading Formula Property

Tags: excel, excel-interop

We have C# code using Excel Interop that is trying to read `Range.Formula` as a 2-dimensional array. We got a COM Exception (0x800A03EC) when doing so. Here is a minimal working example to demo the issue (parametrised on a `Range` object):

```
    public void ReadFormulas(Range range)
    {
        var formulas = range.Formula;
    }
```

We couldn't figure this out for some time. Most of the time it worked. But sometimes, when reading certain data, we got this exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was as follows:

1. The range we were trying to read, contained a cell with a *value* in it that had > 10K  characters in it. This was OK, because the cell's value was just a value - not starting with an "=" sign. And according to [Excel Specifications and Limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3), the "Total number of characters that a cell can contain" is 32,767 characters.
2. However, when reading the entire 2D range as an array of *formulas*, this value was too long, because by [Excel Specifications and Limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3), the maximum "Length of formula contents" is 8,192 characters. Therefore, the read failed.

In fact, this could be reproduced without even needing to read the 2D array. We just used the following VBA to reproduce, selecting a single cell with > 8,192 characters:

```
Sub Test()
    Formula = Selection.Formula
    Debug.Print Formula
End Sub
```

Putting cell contents into the selected cell that exceeded 8,192 characters was fine - because they were just treated as a *value*, but when trying to read that value as a *formula*, the script failed. In contrast, reading as a value still works:

```
Sub Test()
    Value = Selection.Value
    Debug.Print Value
End Sub
```

As a workaround, we are thinking of devising a solution as follows:

1. Catch the COM exception if it occurs
2. Read the values as a 2D-array
3. Search the values array for entries exceeding the formula limit
4. Break up the formula read accorindgly based on any too-large entries found. E.g. if we are reading range `A1:F20` and we find a cell with > 8,192 characters as cell B12, we could then break our formula read into a number of reads of the following ranges: `A1:A20`, `B1:B11`, `B13:B20`, `C1:F20`. Then we can fill in a 2D array in memory with these values and finally populate the entry for `B12` using the *value* we originally read.